# iphone web design issue

Tags: iphone

Hi i created a design for iphone

http://crossbiz.net/propertiesNG/

with auto width but the issue is when i which look ok in iphone tester 
but when i open it in iphone it zoom decreases

plz help

Answer (score 0):

Just set the property for scale to no.

> myWebView.scalesPageToFit = NO;

[UIWebView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/scalesPageToFit)